# Css transition not transitioning back to original state when using animation with it

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

I am trying to make a loading animation. I am using css transition to transition into the loading by scaling and then using animation to scale out the x axis. But when I try to transition back to the original state it doesn't use the transition anymore it just snaps back. I could use animation for the whole thing but I want to account for the page continuing  to load so I don't want to have to write extra javascript logic to handle it. It would be nice if It would just transition on its own.

When you click the following snippet the first time it works fine. But when you click it again it just snaps back to its original state and doesn't use the transition. If you use a different property like opacity in the animation part then it works fine so I'm assuming there is something with the browser not recognizing the current scaled value. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

```js
document.querySelector('.wrapper').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('.wrapper').classList.toggle('loading')
})
```

```css
.wrapper{
  position:fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:  100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper > div{
  color: white;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  transition: transform 500ms ease-out;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.wrapper.loading > div{
  transform: scale(0.2, 0.002);
  animation: loading 1000ms ease-out infinite;
  animation-delay: 500ms;
}

@keyframes loading {
  0%{
    transform: scale(0.2, 0.002)
  }
  50%{
    transform: scale(0.5, 0.002)
  }
  100%{
    transform: scale(0.2, 0.002)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>click me</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

I believe that this happens because CSS transition eventually gives a class two states and transitions between them, when you remove your class you don't change its state, you remove it. my solution would be to add another class to set it back.

---

CSS transitions work by defining two states for the object using CSS. In your case, you define how the object looks when it has the class "loading" and you define how it looks when it doesn't have the class "saved" (it's normal look). When you remove the class "loading", it will transition to the other state according to the transition settings in place for the object without the "loading" class.

If the CSS transition settings apply to the object (without the "loading" class), then they will apply to both transitions.

your transition CSS settings only apply to .saved and thus when you remove it, there are no controls to specify a CSS setting. You may want to add another class ".fade" that you leave on the object all the time and you can specify your CSS transition settings on that class so they are always in effect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a pure css fix for this.

But you can add a different class with a animation that restores to what it was before with JS

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");

wrapper.onclick = () => {
  if ([...wrapper.classList].includes("loading")) {
    wrapper.classList.add("restore");
  } else {
    wrapper.classList.remove("restore");
  }
  
  wrapper.classList.toggle("loading");
};
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper>div {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  animation: none;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 500ms ease-out;
}

.wrapper.restore>div {
  animation: restore 500ms ease-out;
}

.wrapper.loading>div {
  transform: scale(0.2, 0.002);
  animation: loading 1000ms 500ms ease-out infinite;
}

@keyframes restore {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.2, 0.002);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes loading {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.2, 0.002)
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.5, 0.002)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.2, 0.002)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>click me</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use animation iteration count property:

```
div {
   animation-iteration-count: 2;
}
```

or use fill mode to freeze the animation at the end:

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

Comment: This would  stop the animation. I want the animation to be infinite. That is why in my example i have infinite in the animation property.